# get co-ordinates within a user's specified radius

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates, radius

I have a database of users who each have an associated longitude, latitude, radius (in m) and notificationID value stored.

When a user logs in to my app, I will check their longitude and latitude and I need to retrieve a list of notificationIDs which follow this criteria:

User A wants to receive notifications from those within a 1000m radius. 
User B wants to receive notifications from those within a 20000m radius.
User C wants to receive notifications from those within a 5000m radius.

So if User C sends out a push notification, it may be received by User B and not User A even if User A is actually closer to User C than it is to User B.

Apologies if this is unclear, I'm finding it hard to explain.

I have done a query before which will return co-ordinates of those within a certain range e.g. 50m (below) but the bit I'm struggling with is the calculation of each person's individual radius and how that will relate to if they will receive a notification from other users.

```
set @orig_lat= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Latitude']);
set @orig_lon=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Longitude']);
set @dist= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Distance']);

$Search_Query= "SELECT *,
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -
abs( 
dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( 
abs
(dest.lat) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.lon) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))
as distance FROM hotels dest having distance < @distORDER BY distance limit 10";
```

Comment: OT: I would consider PostgreSQL/PostGIS backend if tasks like this are primary goal of your application.

Answer (score 0):

That query will use a full table scan every time. That's why people use GIS (not sure why TLama thinks you should switch DBMS, MySQL has geospatial capability too).

You didn't say what level of accuracy you need. If it were me, I'd probably not bother with circles and GIS though - just use a bounding box after you've worked out the radius into horizantal and vertical degrees. This could be implemented within the where clause allowing effective use of indexes. The box would include an extra 22% of area in the corners - but you can filter those out in the HAVING clause.